# Excel Olap PivotTable Fields Collapse by default

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

When I connect to an OLAP data source in Excel and pivot, there are a list of dimensions and measure groups shown.  These are expanded by default.  Like below:

[image]

There is an option to "collapse all" under the Tools (cog icon) but I have to select it every time.  I want it to look like below by default when i first connect.

[image]

Does anybody know if there is a registry hack or option in Excel that controls this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in PivotTable Field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however this isnt a setting it's an action and isn't permanent.  I wanted this to default to collapsed whenever Excel is opened.

Comment: I think this requirement cannot be achieved. Excel cannot record this action macro code.